# Getting this error when I run a test on truffle : sets the total supply upon deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle

When I try to run a test from truffle, I got this problem, here my test js code:

```
var YarockToken=artifacts.require("./YarockToken.sol");
contract('YarockToken',function(accounts){

var tokenInstance;

it('set the total supply upon deployment', function(){
    return YarockToken.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance=instance;
        return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
    }).then(function(totalSupply){
        assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(),1000000,'sets the total supply to 1,000,000');
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);

    }).then(function(adminBalance){
        assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(),1000000,'it allocates the initial supply to the admin account');
    });
});
});
```

and here my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;



contract YarockToken{
//Constructor 
//Set total number of tokens
//Read the total number of tokens
uint public totalSupply;

mapping(address=> uint256) public balanceOf;

constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public{
    balanceOf[msg.sender]=_initialSupply;
    totalSupply=_initialSupply;
}

}
```

and here is the result of the test

```
❰C❙~/token_sale(git:master)❱✘≻ truffle test
Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.
Using network 'test'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/YarockToken.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/folders/v2/b8d1nl855pnd92c67c95j4nc0000gn/T/test--88304-0azTwJ2IV7q2
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.


  Contract: YarockToken
    1) set the total supply upon deployment
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (149ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: YarockToken
       set the total supply upon deployment:
     ReferenceError: accounts is not defined
      at /Users/Kantemirovs/token_sale/test/YarockToken.js:13:35
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Transcribing the result rather than posting a screenshot will help.  The post will be more accessible.

Comment: The error says it all ```ReferenceError: accounts is not defined```. There is something wrong with your local blockchain, what are you using? Ganache, testrpc or any other? Start with debugging this, make sure your local testing blockchain is running and also make sure the connection between the project and the blockchain is working.

Comment: Using ganache, I was able to run the tests successfully. I'd agree with Miroslav's comments for where to start debugging. It also seems odd that you have both a `truffle-config.js` and `truffle.js` this should be one file - maybe there is a configuration you are not expecting in one of them.